# Loading srfi in guile scheme

Tags: scheme, guile

I found out that the srfi's already used
live under /user/guile/3.0/srfi/. This is also in the load-path variable.
Now I go into /user/guile/3.0/srfi/ and 'git clone github-link-to-srfi-25' but I can not load the code via

```
(use-module
    (srfi srfi-25))
```

in geiser.
I noticed that the other srfi's living there don't consist of
git projects and also sometimes are 100 % html code so I am really
confused right now on how to use code in the srfi. Do I have to
define the module myself?

Comment: The source files in the SRFI-25 source archive on github are not in guile module format...

Comment: I guess this is intentional. So what is the standard way of using these kinds of srfi's in your code base?

Comment: Modern SRFI reference implementations often provide R6RS and/or R7RS modules that Guile can load when those standards are enabled (See sections 7.6 and 7.7 in the manual). But 25 is very old, and doesn't. The standard way would be to either write your own implementation, or take the reference code and port it by hand to a particular scheme.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I recognize the srfi's that are in the right format?